# Алгоритм польской нотации(обратной)

Tags: алгоритм

Запишите пожалуйста следующее выражение в обратной польской нотации:
(1+2)*3^4^5-6/(7+8/9)

Comment: @Semen  Savenko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @insolor, ok, я изучил материал и вообще не пойму как работать с такими сложными выражениями, это рандомное выражение для теста

Comment: @Semen Savenko ну а мы то тут причем ? думаете если вы добрались до форума с подсказками это дает вам право занимать не принадлежащие вам место ? ведь если такого как вы не возьмут на  работу или выгонят из универа, мир станет только лучше.

Comment: @eicto, IMHO вот тут Вы не правы. Иногда ведь надо подсказать человеку, подтолкнуть его в правильном направлении.

А если в конечном итоге **это** окажется не его, что ж... сам уйдет.

Comment: Эх, не было у человека программируемого калькулятора со стеком и обратной польской записью :) . Интересная вещь, позволяет более экономно записывать вычисления, например, т.к. не нужны скобки. Почитайте http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.92.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотел ограничиться комментарием, но ничего разумного в ограничение размера комментария не уместилось...

[@Semen](/users/574/semen) Savenko, разбейте сложное выражение на простые (которые понимаете), потом объедините.

Например, из:

```
 (1+2)*3^4^5
```

получится (учитывая скобки и приоритет ^ (предполагая, что это степень, а не xor)):

```
 1,2,+,3,4,5,^,^,*
```

а :

```
 6/(7+8/9)
```

даст

```
 6,7,8,9,/,+,/
```

Ну, последний шаг сделайте сами.

Вообще алгоритм трансляции заключается в использовании 2-х стеков (один операндов, а другой операций) и переносе элементов из них в результат в правильном (определяется  приоритетом операций) порядке.

При таком подходе скобки можно считать операциями. Закрывающая (считаем, что у нее самый высокий приоритет) будет "выталкивать" другие операции и соответственно нужные им операнды из стеков, пока не встретит открывающую скобку в стеке операций (а у нее приоритет самый низкий).

Далее сами.

Comment: Если трансляция производится вручную (или при помощи парсера), можно преобразовать выражение в дерево, а затем обойти его в [обратном порядке](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) (сначала ветки, потом корень).